# Inverse transform function is not returning correct value

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, multilabel-classification

I am following tutorial for multi labeling movie genre from https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/predicting-movie-genres-nlp-multi-label-classification/

I am using that tutorial to create prediction tag for complaint register. In my case, I am labeling 'Genre' for Complaint Register such as 1 complaint can have many label/tag of Genre). For example: Complaint #1 has multi Genre = Warranty, Air Conditioning.

I am up to the stage where I am invoking multilablebinarizer() function to label the movie 'Genre'

My issue is as following:

The total unique Genre = 55 (Please see screenshot below)
image.png

I ran Multilabel_binarizer function and transform "Genre" target variable into y.

Questions:

1. I encounter y only has (166,49). If my understanding is correct, there is only 49 Genre as opposed to 55 unique Genre
2. I encounter error message: 
   C:\Users\LAUJ3\Documents\Python Project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py:74: UserWarning: Label not 47 is present in all training examples.
   warnings.warn("Label %s is present in all training examples." %
3. The inverse_transfrom function of multilabel_binarizer result does not make sense. Expected to see the Genre label instead of Gibberish
      multilabel_binarizer.inverse_transform(y_pred)[3]

   y_pred[3]
      Out[57]:
      array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

   multilabel_binarizer.inverse_transform(y_pred)[3]
     Out[58]: (' ', ',', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'r', 't')

I don't know what went wrong. Thanks for your help in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0v4f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb =  MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit_transform(df['genre'])

print(mlb.classes_)
#op
[' ' '"' '&' "'" ',' '-' '/' '0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' ':'
'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'G' 'H' 'I' 'J' 'K' 'L' 'M' 'N' 'O' 'P' 'Q' 'R'
'S' 'T' 'V' 'W' 'Z' '[' '\\' ']' '_' 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i'
'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' '{'
'}']
```

you are getting character as class, because the content of df['genre'] is string

```
#printing type of df['genre']
print(type(df['genre'][0]))
#op
<class 'str'>
```

convert genre column into dict and pull out value

```
df['genre'] = df['genre'].apply(lambda x :[value for value in eval(x).values()])
print(type(df['genre'][0]))
#op
<class 'list'>
```

now you can apply MultilabelBinarizer do df['genre'] column, and now inverse_transform will work for you

```
mlb.fit_transform(df['genre'])
print(mlb.classes_[0:10]) # taking only 10 element from array since there is 363 different classes

#op
array(['Absurdism', 'Acid western', 'Action', 'Action Comedy',
   'Action Thrillers', 'Action/Adventure', 'Addiction Drama', 'Adult',
   'Adventure', 'Adventure Comedy'], dtype=object)
```

updated code

```
#replace  df['genre'] = df['genre'].apply(lambda x :[value for value in eval(x).values()])
df['Genre'] = df['Genre'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')) 
mlb.fit_transform(df1['Genre'])

print(mlb.classes_)
#op
array([' Curtain/Blinds', ' Delays', ' Electricial Compliance',
   ' Granny Flat', ' Heating/Cooling', ' Payment', ' Refund',
   ' Unlicensed', ' Warranty', 'Airconditioning', 'Heating/Cooling',
   'Warranty'], dtype=object
```

in earlier data it with string with dictionary format, but in your data string is comma separated, you don't need to use eval function simple split will work for you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right that the column is in STR class. I tried to follow your code and try to convert it to list but I received an error indicating the value in the column is undefined. Not sure by this.

Tag['Genre'] = Tag['Genre'].apply(lambda x :[value for value in eval(x).values()])

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'Airconditioning' is not defined

Comment: Please let me know if you can open https://drive.google.com/open?id=10yLOVWZPgl1shVwwM5qDy7iyMCm7cS9A

Comment: i have used  movie.metadata.tsv the link that was given in analyticsvidhya for data, Learning Data 9-12-2019.xls  that you have used  and movie.metadata.tsv is same or you have done some modification ????

Comment: I used my own file but formatted the file in xls file format so I can skip the clean-up process. The file is also in that google drive (with only 4 columns including 'Genre').

Comment: I only used single file that has 4 columns.

Comment: I have a feeling that I have not converted that 'Genre' column (multiple value in a list format) properly

Comment: I came across a problem in the beginning when following the tutorial to convert the 'Genre' column into list and append it back to the DF (Tag). The tutorial is referring to using JSON.

Please see: Genre_convert_to_list_JSON.txt
https://drive.google.com/open?id=10yLOVWZPgl1shVwwM5qDy7iyMCm7cS9A

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @J.L , no need to convert to json , it will work .. i have updated the code.. instead of eval use split  by comma it will work

Comment: Thank you so much!

 Just to share here as well. I found out the way to convert multivalue column into a list.

#Create an empty array called Test
#Tag -> Dataframe name
#Genre -> Column name

Test = []
Test = Tag['Genre'].str.split(", ").tolist()

Tag['genre_new'] = Test

Comment: do you think you can help me with my new post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349516/label-not-x-is-present-in-all-training-examples @qaiser